# Using iterator interface or for each statement in Java

Tags: java

```
Stack<String> sk = new Stack<String>();

sk.push("Hello");
sk.push("Hello1");
sk.push("Hello2");
```

There are two ways i am iterating this Stack Object.

```
for(String s : sk){
   System.out.println("The Values of String in SK" +sk);
}
```

// Way two..

```
Iterator<String> it=sk.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        String iValue=(String)it.next();
        System.out.println("Iterator value :"+iValue);
    }
```

1. What is the difference between these two?
2. Any Advantage if i choose one among them?
3. Which is the preferred way of iterating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***1. What is the difference between these two?***

Not much. The for-each loop construct actually relies on the iterator behind the curtains.

**Further reading:**

- [The For-Each Loop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html), official documentation / tutorial

> ***2. Any Advantage if i choose one among them?***

Mostly readability I would assume.

(If you need to access the `iterator.remove()` method, then obviously you would need to go with the explicit `Iterator` approach.) However, keep in mind that it's an optional operation and may not be supported by the underlying `Stack` implementation you're using.

Besides, the point of a `Stack` structure is that you *don't* remove elements in the middle.

> ***3. Which is the preferred way of iterating?***

Use the for-each approach, if that works for you.

Answer (score 4):

The `Iterator` has the advantage that you can remove elements from the collection while iterating over it. Foreach may throw `ConcurrentModificationExceptions` there.

If you don't need that, I prefer the former way because it is easier to read.

Comment: Why would he use a `Stack` if he needs to remove elements from the middle of the collection?

Answer (score 2):

with the `Iterator` you can prevent a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`, when you modify the list while looping over them. [Iterator.remove()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

From *Effective Java*, by Joshua Bloch:

> The `for` loop, in both its traditional and `for-each` forms, allows you to declare loop
>   variables, limiting their scope to the exact region where they’re needed. (This
>   region consists of the body of the loop as well as the initialization, test, and update
>   preceding the body.)Therefore, **prefer `for` loops to `while` loops**, assuming the
>   contents of the loop variable aren’t needed after the loop terminates.

To make it short:

- the `for-each` loop is **always** type safe
- the `for-each` loop is less prone to copy/paste errors (copy/paste iterator1 twice in your code!)
- the `for-each` loop  allows you to minimize the scope of local variables
- the `for-each` loop is easier to read!

In summary, **prefer `for-each` loops to `while` loops** when you do not explicitly need a `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing between For each and an `Iterator` is just a matter of convenience. For each loop looks a bit cryptic especially to those who are used to the traditional for loop. The downside with `Iterator`s, however, is that you've to cast the `Object` from the `next()` to the appropriate type, although your collection is not typed. With For each, everything is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Actually, since java 1.5, Iterator is generic, so you don't need a cast if you added the appropriate generic parameters to your collection and iterator

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between these two?

Nothing. Except for the extra code

> Any Advantage if I choose one among them?

Yes. If you use the newer one (foreach), you have fewer lines and are therefore easier to read.

> Which is the preferred way of iterating?

The foreach loop

You may want to read [Nuances of the Java 5.0 for-each Loop](http://today.java.net/article/2006/11/03/nuances-java-50-each-loop) and the [official for-each loop tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)